# How to left join two Datables?

Tags: c#, linq

Here i my Scenario

I Have First Datable :TableA

```
SerialNumber   PartNumber
    001               A
    002               B

        var TableA = (from p in ddata.AsEnumerable()
                 join q in Select.AsEnumerable()
                   on p.Field<string>("SerialNumber") equals q.Field<string>("SerialNumber") 
                  select new
                   {
                       SerialNUmber = q["SerialNumber"],
                       PartNumber = q["PartNumber"],
                        UnitStatus = "HOT"
               }).ToList();
```

Second Table :TableB

```
SerialNumber  PartNumber
001             A
002             B
003             C
004             D

   var merger = (from w in ddata.AsEnumerable()
                              select new
                              {
                                  SerialNUmber = w["SerialNumber"],
                                  PartNumber = w["PartNumber"],
                                  UnitStatus = "COLD"
                              }).ToList();
```

Requirement:

Join The Two Datatables and Show Result Case if Serials is equal to both Table then Status is HOT else NORMAL.

```
SerialNumber  PartNumber    Status
001             A           HOT
002             B           HOT
003             C           NORMAL
004             D           NORMAL
```

Is this Possible?Thanks in Regrads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most certainly possible although I used 'Intersect', 'Except', and 'Union' instead of a left join.  I hope that is acceptable:

```
var both = list1.Intersect(list2);
var ret = both
              .Select(x => new { SerialNumber = x.SerialNumber, PartNumber = x.PartNumber, Status = "HOT" })
              .Union(
                  list1.Union(list2).Distinct()
                      .Except(both)
                      .Select(x => new { SerialNumber = x.SerialNumber, PartNumber = x.PartNumber, Status = "NORMAL" })
              )
```

LinqPad test:

```
var list1 = new [] {
new { SerialNumber = 1, PartNumber = "A" },
new { SerialNumber = 2, PartNumber = "B" },
};

var list2 = new [] {
new { SerialNumber = 1, PartNumber = "A" },
new { SerialNumber = 2, PartNumber = "B" },
new { SerialNumber = 3, PartNumber = "C" },
new { SerialNumber = 4, PartNumber = "D" },
};

var both = list1.Intersect(list2);
both
    .Select(x => new { SerialNumber = x.SerialNumber, PartNumber = x.PartNumber, Status = "HOT" })
    .Union(
        list1.Union(list2).Distinct()
            .Except(both)
            .Select(x => new { SerialNumber = x.SerialNumber, PartNumber = x.PartNumber, Status = "NORMAL" })
    )
.Dump();
```

Returns:

```
SerialNumber PartNumber Status 
1            A          HOT
2            B          HOT
3            C          NORMAL
4            D          NORMAL
```

Comment: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'dump' and no extension method 'dump' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Dump is an object extension method available in the program linqpad (http://www.linqpad.net/) that displays information about an object in a console-esque window. Linqpad is a tool to rapidly create linq and linq to sql scripts, sort of a mini IDE if you will.  You don't need it for this which is why I posted the same code first without the 'Dump()' call above the linq test.  Just get rid of the 'Dump()' call and it should work fine.